# Text in MS Charts gets "blocky" when BackColor is transparent

Tags: asp.net, transparent, mschart, backcolor

When settings BackColor = Color.Transparent, this is the picture I end up with from Microsofts asp.net chart control

http://login.competencetool.se/blockychart.bmp

If I don't set any background(default is white), or set a color this is the result

change the image to okchart.bmp

Does anyone know if there's any way to get the font/text to don't get messed up when using transparent background?

I wasn't allowed to link the images, so look at the adresses.

Comment: Nice... `.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` is the culprit indeed. Just changed it to `Color.White` and now the `AntiAliasingStyles.All` is just perfect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set chart's **AntiAliasing** to **AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics** to disable the antialiasing on text.

Taken from [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/64c7d890-c98b-4392-9ec9-1b4af3e24300).